# Why has the NoScript icon disappeared?

Tags: windows, firefox, noscript

Why has the appearance of [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) changed?

I am using NoScript in Firefox (Microsoft Windows):

Until now there has been an icon (the S icon) in the lower
right of the screen. But now there is an button instead with
the text "Options". Left clicking this button seems to bring
up the menu as right clicking the old icon.

Can I restore the previous state?

Is there an auto-update function in NoScript and if so could
it have caused the change? If it exists can the auto-update
function be disabled?

---

Platform: Firefox 3.0.6, NoScript 1.9.0.6, Windows XP 64 bit, 8 GB RAM.

Comment: sounds odd. Try update NoScript? think there are newer version than 1.9.0.6 (got 1.9.7 myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened because the Status Bar was disabled. Solution: use menu View/Status Bar to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

As for how it happened, Firefox has an option to search for updates to your addons automatically.  Do you have this selected?  It is under Options->Advanced->Update.

As for whether you should worry: no.  Does it all still work?  If so, then you'll get used to the UI change soon enough.  If there seems to be some functionality missing, try going to the [NoScript website](http://noscript.net/) and looking at the [release notes](http://noscript.net/changelog) for that version.

Changing it back: there may be a setting in NoScript that will show the icon again.  You'll have to find that yourself (if it exists).  You could also uninstall the addon and reinstall an older version (can probably find old versions on the website).  Is this recommended?  No.  Generally updates are done for a reason, and a UI change is often not worth going back a version over.

Comment: I have all updates turned off. In any case it is good to know where to look for these settings.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox by default checks for plugin updates automatically, and then let you choose if you want to download and install them. As far as I can tell there is no automatic update without user interaction.

You can disable this check in the browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue--the NoScript icon had disappeared and wouldn't reinstall.

The solution was to uninstall "McAfee SiteAdvisor". Once I went to *Control Panel* → *Programs* → uninstall Mcafee Sitadvisor. Firefox restarted and NoScript was back.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 4 the solution is to look under the View menu, click Toolbars, and click the Add-on bar.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about the same icon, for me it went from the addon toolbar to the navigation bar.

I went to "Views -> Toolbars -> Customise" (or similar, have a German interface here) and then I moved the icon by dragging it from the navigation bar down to the addon bar.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a page called Add-ons that you access by going in the "Tools" Dropdown box. (On my MacBook it's at the top of the screen.)

By bringing up the Add-ons page - a listing of all Add-ons you've chosen - you will see the line with the NoScript Add-on listed. If you then hit "MORE", you >CAN choose to< select to STOP NoScript from continually updating itself, regularly, automatically on Firefox.

I probably wouldn't suggest doing that, as NoScript regularly adds fixes and updates to its scripts' response programming. But I wanted to let you know that it IS possible to select that (stopping the NoScript auto-updating) and not have to change the the overall auto-update status for Firefox, or your computer in general.

You're better off recreating/resurrecting the missing icon/button. I found MY missing NoScript Button on my Addon Bar, which I had UN-enabled (because I had had nothing on it & because the Status Bar seems to work better for me). By going (in Firefox) under the "View" Dropdown you can select "Toolbars" and then select/unselect 'Status Bar' and 'The Addon Bar'.

After I found my missing NoScript Button I went to the near-top /right of the Firefox Window/Screen and selected the Open Menu Tool - which is the =three=horizontal=lines=, one atop the other (looking like a FAT partial I-Ching Hexagram).

Once that box opens, at the bottom of the box you can select "Customize" - for Customizing Menu & Toolbars. After that's selected you can move around and rearrange icon items on various toolbars. I found my missing NoScript button on the now visible "Status Bar" (which I had just before re-enabled thru the "View" dropdown), and I MOVED it back to the Status Bar where it had previously been.

You can put the NoScript icon /button, or most anything else, almost ANYWHERE on these Firefox Window toolbars - where-ever you want them.  But, be slightly advised that occasionally moving too many things around makes something seem to disappear again. I've had that happen and had to uninstall/delete the relevant Firefox Add-On, and then re-install it, just to get the missing button back.  USUALLY, however, moving these little icon/buttons around isn't too much of any problem.

Good luck!